# How would I mimic testing then() response with Jasmine, using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Here's my code

```
 function guestDeviceManagerController(guestService, status) {
   vm.initState = function() {
     guestService.isUserAdmin(status.standardId).then(function(isAdmin) {
       vm.isAdmin = isAdmin;
       vm.template = vm.isAdmin ? vm.templates[0] : vm.templates[1];
     }, function() {
       //TODO: display user error
     });
   };
   vm.initState();
 }
```

I would like to know how to mimic this requests and where it should be done in SpyOn(), and if so I need to tests for response being returned as false and true.

Made the following modifications:

```
describe('guestDeviceManagerController Tests', function() {
  'use strict';
  var scope,
    controller,
    statusService,
    guestService,
    q;


  beforeEach(function() {
    module('mainApp');
    module('mobileDevicesModule');

    inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $q, _statusService_, _guestService_) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      statusService = _statusService_;
      guestService = _guestService_;
      q = $q;

      controller = $controller('guestController', {
        $scope: scope,
        guestService: guestService
      });
    });

  });



  it('Assert view that should render for admin', function() {

    spyOn(guestService, 'isUserAdmin').and.returnValue(q.when(true));
    scope.$apply();
    controller.initState();

    expect(controller.template.url).toEqual('app/mobile-devices/guest/admin/guest.html');
  });


});
```

and now getting the following error: Error: Unexpected request: GET http://localhost:34327/guest//IsAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the success path with a true isAdmin result:

```
spyOn(guestService, 'isUserAdmin').andReturn($q.when(true));
```

To test the success path with a false isAdmin result:

```
spyOn(guestService, 'isUserAdmin').andReturn($q.when(false));
```

To test the error path:

```
spyOn(guestService, 'isUserAdmin').andReturn($q.reject());
```

Read the [$q documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Make sure to call `$rootScope.$apply()` to actually resolve/reject the promises when you want to.

For example:

```
// spy the service:
spyOn(guestService, 'isUserAdmin').andReturn($q.when(true));
// instantiate the controller:
$controller('guestDeviceManagerController');
// resolve/reject the promises. This will cause the callback functions to be called
$rootScope.$apply();
// now test that the callback has done what it's supposed to do
```

Comment: inside what? What do you mean?

Comment: I need to run one it('assertiont test') that will have response as true and one that will have it as false, so my question is does spyOn go inside it()?

Comment: If you want to test all the cases, then yes, there should be 3 tests, each spying on the service and making it do what you want in the test.

Comment: has andReturn been deprecated in Jasmine 2.0?

Comment: Yes. If using jasmine 2, use `and.returnValue()`. http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88575/discussion-between-eugenekgn-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: Mine looks something like this
    inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $q) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            q = $q;

   it('Assert view that should render for admin', function () {

        spyOn(guestNetworkService, 'isUserAdmin').and.returnValue(q.when(true));

        controller.initState();
        scope.$apply();


and I get an error: Error: Unexpected request: GET http://localhost:11111/network//IsAdmin

Any advice? You've been awesome - thank you. I wish i can send you an e-drink coupon :-)

Comment: Code is unreadable in a comment. Edit your question and post the complete code in the question.

Comment: You're injecting _statusService_ twice, and not _guestService_. You're also contructing the controller **before** spying on the service, so, since the initState() is called as soon as the controller is instanciated, it calls the non-spied service, which sends an HTTP request. Re-read the example in my answer.